# Element will not go away using click() method to transition element opacity

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to program the element with an ID of "opacity" to change its opacity from 1 to 0 upon clicking the element. But then I click the element, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

```css
#message {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 10, 10, .5);
  overflow: scroll;
}

.box {
  background-color: blue;
}

#background {
  background-color: red;
}

.submenu {
  background-color: purple;
  color: green;
  width: 150px;
}

.option {
  background-color: cyan;
}

#dashboard {
  margin-left: -70px;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 80px;
  border: 5px solid;
}

#opacity {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

img.faded {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- The above DOCTYPE declaration tells the browser that this page conforms to HTML 5 standards -->

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="author" content="Chris" />
  <link href="jquery.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      jQuery('#one').hide();
      jQuery('#fadeToggle').click(function() {
        jQuery('#one').fadeToggle(500);
      });
      jQuery('#fadeTo').click(function() {
        jQuery('#two').fadeTo(500, .5);
      });
      jQuery('#congrats').animate({
          marginLeft: '+=1200px',
        },
        10000,
      );
      jQuery('#congrats').fadeOut(11000);
      jQuery('#opacity').click(function() {
        jQuery(this).addClass('faded');
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="one">
    <p>This is the fadeToggle() method carrying out a "well-defined operation on data," the jQuery object ('#box'), in this case. The parameter is "500," which stands for half a second.</p>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" id="fadeToggle" value="fadeToggle()" />
  <div id="two">
    <p>This is the fadeTo() method.</p>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" id="fadeTo" value="fadeToggle()" />
  <div id="heading">
    <img id="congrats" src="congrats.gif" />
  </div>
  <img id="opacity" src="congrats.gif" />
</body>

</html>
```

I am trying to program the element with an ID of "opacity" to change its opacity from 1 to 0 upon clicking the element. But then I click the element, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: 404 Not Found : https://stacksnippets.net/jquery.js

Comment: @onyx How do you mean? I have the jQuery file connected to my HTML file. Furthermore, the click function to use the fadeOut() method works in the same document for the "fadeTo" ID.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the jQuery `.css()` method to set the `opacity` to `0`.

This is because in your CSS stylesheet, you have given `#opacity` an `opacity` of `1`, which can not be overriden by adding another class with an `opacity` of `0`. You have to add an inline style to override the CSS properties set in the stylesheet with `.css()`.

```css
#message {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 10, 10, .5);
  overflow: scroll;
}

.box {
  background-color: blue;
}

#background {
  background-color: red;
}

.submenu {
  background-color: purple;
  color: green;
  width: 150px;
}

.option {
  background-color: cyan;
}

#dashboard {
  margin-left: -70px;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 80px;
  border: 5px solid;
}

#opacity {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

img.faded {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- The above DOCTYPE declaration tells the browser that this page conforms to HTML 5 standards -->

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="author" content="Chris" />
  <script>
    $(function() {
      jQuery('#one').hide();
      jQuery('#fadeToggle').click(function() {
        jQuery('#one').fadeToggle(500);
      });
      jQuery('#fadeTo').click(function() {
        jQuery('#two').fadeTo(500, .5);
      });
      jQuery('#congrats').animate({
          marginLeft: '+=1200px',
        },
        10000,
      );
      jQuery('#congrats').fadeOut(11000);
      jQuery('#opacity').click(function() {
        jQuery(this).css("opacity", "0");
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="one">
    <p>This is the fadeToggle() method carrying out a "well-defined operation on data," the jQuery object ('#box'), in this case. The parameter is "500," which stands for half a second.</p>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" id="fadeToggle" value="fadeToggle()" />
  <div id="two">
    <p>This is the fadeTo() method.</p>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" id="fadeTo" value="fadeToggle()" />
  <div id="heading">
    <img id="congrats" src="congrats.gif" />
  </div>
  <img id="opacity" src="congrats.gif" />
</body>

</html>
```

You can make the opacity rule in `.faded` more important by adding `!important`.

```css
#message {
      height: 300px;
      width: 300px;
      background-color: rgb(255, 10, 10, .5);
      overflow: scroll;
    }

    .box {
      background-color: blue;
    }

    #background {
      background-color: red;
    }

    .submenu {
      background-color: purple;
      color: green;
      width: 150px;
    }

    .option {
      background-color: cyan;
    }

    #dashboard {
      margin-left: -70px;
      background-color: blue;
      width: 80px;
      border: 5px solid;
    }

    #opacity {
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
      -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
      -o-transition: opacity 1s;
      transition: opacity 1s;
    }

    img.faded {
      opacity: 0 !important;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="author" content="Chris" />
      <script>
        $(function() {
          jQuery('#one').hide();
          jQuery('#fadeToggle').click(function() {
            jQuery('#one').fadeToggle(500);
          });
          jQuery('#fadeTo').click(function() {
            jQuery('#two').fadeTo(500, .5);
          });
          jQuery('#congrats').animate({
              marginLeft: '+=1200px',
            },
            10000,
          );
          jQuery('#congrats').fadeOut(11000);
          jQuery('#opacity').click(function() {
            jQuery(this).addClass("faded");
          });
        });
      </script>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div id="one">
        <p>This is the fadeToggle() method carrying out a "well-defined operation on data," the jQuery object ('#box'), in this case. The parameter is "500," which stands for half a second.</p>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" id="fadeToggle" value="fadeToggle()" />
      <div id="two">
        <p>This is the fadeTo() method.</p>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" id="fadeTo" value="fadeToggle()" />
      <div id="heading">
        <img id="congrats" src="congrats.gif" />
      </div>
      <img id="opacity" src="congrats.gif" />
    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `faded` class will not change the `opacity` attribute since there's a direct rule related to `#opacity` element that force the `opacity` attribute value to be `1` :

```
#opacity {
    opacity: 1;
____^^^^^^^^^^
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

That will be always applied since according to the **specificity hierarchy** the `id` attribute has more weight than the `class`, to force the class rule you could use `!important` :

```
img.faded {
  opacity: 0.5 !important;
}
```

```js
$(function() {
  jQuery('#opacity').click(function() {
    jQuery(this).addClass('faded');
  });
});
```

```css
#opacity {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

img.faded {
  opacity: 0.5 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</div>
<img id="opacity" src="congrats.gif" />
```

You could write a more specific rule using the id `#opacity` like :

```
img#opacity.faded {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```js
$(function() {
  jQuery('#opacity').click(function() {
    jQuery(this).addClass('faded');
  });
});
```

```css
#opacity {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

img#opacity.faded {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</div>
<img id="opacity" src="congrats.gif" />
```

I prefer the use of `css()` method to set the opacity instead, like :

```
jQuery(this).css({opacity: 0});
```

```js
$(function() {
  jQuery('#opacity').click(function() {
    jQuery(this).css({
      opacity: 0
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#opacity {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

img.faded {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</div>
<img id="opacity" src="congrats.gif" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update the css. Your css `#opacity` is overwriting your `img.faded`. All you need to do is `#opacity.faded` [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/cakibovola/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

```
#opacity.faded {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an **id** that is setting *opacity: 1* and then you're adding a **class** with *opacity: 0*, this creates a conflict.

If you wanted to make a simple change to this, then you can just add **!important** to your faded class css so it takes presidents over the id.

Like this:

```
.faded {
  opacity: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: I've added the !important string, and nothing happens.